# Time complexity of the following recurrence equation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

Hi all I'm having problems calculating the complexity of the following recurrence equation:

```
   T(n)={ O(1)                    ,  if n<=2  
        { 2*T(n^(1/2)) + O(logn)  ,  if n>=2
```

I got to a probable conclusion of O(2^n * nlogn). If anyone has got any clue I'd be happy. Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Master Theorem](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)?

Comment: @Tassle Yes I'm but theoretically since I haven't got the form a*(n/b) I can't use it in that case isn't it?

Comment: Oh I misread that $n^(1/2)$ as $n(1/2)$, sorry.

Comment: @Tassle No problem.

Comment: Question is more appropriate for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @unlut Understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for now that `n > 2` is a power of two, so that you can write `n = 2^m`. Also lets write the constant in your `O(log(n))` term explicitly as `c*log2(n)`.

Then, unravelling the recursion gives us :

```
T(2^m) <= 2*T((2^m)^(1/2)) + c*log2(2^m)
        = 2*T(2^(m/2)) + c*m
       <= 2*( 2*T((2^(m/2))^(1/2)) + c*log2(2^(m/2)) ) + c*m
        = 4*T(2^(m/4)) + 2*c*m
       <= 4*( 2*T((2^(m/4))^(1/2)) + c*log2(2^(m/4)) ) + 2*c*m
        = 8*T(2^(m/8)) + 3*c*m
       <= ...
        = (2^log2(m))*T(2^1) + log2(m)*c*m
        = m*T(2) + c*m*log2(m)
        = log2(n)*T(2) + c*log2(n)*log2(log2(n))
        = O(log2(n)*log2(log2(n)))
```

The term `log2(m)` comes from the fact that we divide `m` by two at each new recursion level, and so it will take (at most) `log2(m)` divisions before `m <= 1`.

Now if n is not a power of two, you can notice that there exists some number `r` which is a power of two such that `n <= r < 2*n`. And you can then write `T(n) <= T(r) = O(log2(r)*log2(log2(r))) = O(log2(2*n)*log2(log2(2*n))) = O(log2(n)*log2(log2(n)))`.

So the overall answer is

```
T(n) = O(log2(n)*log2(log2(n)))
```

Comment: @Luca : I have updated my answer, as I just realized I made a bunch of silly mistakes which made the derivation wrong.